# Symfony3 - Delete Entity with OneToMany - relationship in Doctrine - cascade not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I have two entities:

```
/**
 * Course
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\CourseRepository")
 */
class Course
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection()
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TimeTableEntry", mappedBy="course", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 *
 */
private $timeTableEntries;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $enabled;
```

and

```
/**
 * TimeTableEntry
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\TimeTableEntryRepository")
 */
class TimeTableEntry
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection()
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Course", inversedBy="timeTableEntries", cascade={"ALL"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $course;
```

As you can see I tried with cascade={"ALL"}, onDelete="CASCADE" and orphanRemoval=true.

When I want to delete the Course Entity I get the error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`edutalk`.`teaching_event`, CONSTRAINT `FK_F2B1088B57042871` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`time_table_entry_id`) REFERENCES `time_table_entry` (`id`))

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Please share your entity, not just a snippet.

Comment: Ok, I did it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot comment on your post, so I post it as an answer.

Your problem is that you have another entity `TeachingEvent` with a reference to `TimeTableEntry`. When you try to delete a `TimeTableEntry`, it is impossible because this `time_table_entry_id` is still referenced as a foreign key in the `TeachingEvent` table.

Before deleting the `TimeTableEntry`, first you should unlink it from the `TeachingEvent`. I don't have your code, but depending on how `TimeTableEntry` and `TeachingEvent` relate to each other, it's probably something like:

```
$teachingEvent->setTimeTableEntry(null);
```

or

```
$timeTableEntry->setTeachingEvent(null);
```

Comment: Great! Sometimes its as easy as that. Thank u!